# XUL: How do you create a nested menupopup inside a statusbarpanel (with statusbarpanel-menu-iconic)

Tags: xul

In XUL you can use create a status bar panel icon, similar to the ones used by Firebug and Greasemonkey, with the `<statusbarpanel>` tag.  If you set the right class, you can throw a `<menupop>` inside, and then have a pop-up menu when the user clicks on the icon, like so ...

```
<statusbarpanel class="statusbarpanel-menu-iconic"
        src="chrome://YourExtension/content/icon.png">
    <menupopup>
        <menuitem label="whatever" oncommand="doSomething();">
        <menuitem label="whatever else" oncommand="doSomethingElse();">
    </menupopup>
</statusbarpanel>
```

Now, with other pop-up menus, you can nest a series of menus using the menu tag:

```
<statusbarpanel class="statusbarpanel-menu-iconic"
        src="chrome://YourExtension/content/icon.png">
    <menu value="Old">
        <menupopup>
            <menuitem label="whatever" oncommand="doSomething();">
            <menuitem label="whatever else" oncommand="doSomethingElse();">
        </menupopup>
    </menu>
    <menu value="New>
        <menupopup>
            <menuitem label="yet another" oncommand="doYetAnotherSomething();">
        </menupopup>
    </menu>
</statusbarpanel>
```

but the above code doesn't actually work, because `<statusbarpanel>` won't allow a `<menu>` child (well, it will allow it, but not create the desired effect).

So, what I was wondering was ... is there any way I can make a status bar panel icon-triggered menu with multiple layers of menu items?

*** EDIT ***
Since I can't post this in the comment to the answer (and get syntax coloring and such), here's what finally worked for me (thanks Sathish!):

```
<statusbarpanel class="statusbarpanel-menu-iconic"
        src="chrome://YourExtension/content/icon.png" popup="stausBarPanelMenu">
</statusbarpanel>
<popup id="statusBarPanelMenu" position="start_before">
    <menu value="Old">
        <menupopup>
            <menuitem label="whatever" oncommand="doSomething();">
            <menuitem label="whatever else" oncommand="doSomethingElse();">
        </menupopup>
    </menu>
    <menu value="New>
        <menupopup>
            <menuitem label="yet another" oncommand="doYetAnotherSomething();">
        </menupopup>
    </menu>
</popop>
```

Oh, and as a side note to any XUL devs who might read this: you should really eliminate the "menupopup inside a statusbarpanel" style of pop-up.  The style that answered this question is just as easy to learn/use, significantly more powerful, and it relies on the same popup mechanisms that can be used with the other XUL elements.  This whole "menupopup inside a statusbarpanel" this is just a confusing, un-needed, anomaly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

1. create a popup element like this: 
   `<popup ... >` 
   `<menu ... >` 
   `<menupopup ... >` 
   `<menuitem ... >` 
   `</menupopup ... >` 
   `</menu>` 
   `</popup>`
2. assign the `id` of `popup` element to the `oncontextmenu` attribute or show it dynamically using `onclick` event of the `statusbarpanel` element.

Comment: I don't think there is such a thing as oncontextmenu, and onclick logic shouldn't be needed for this sort of thing, but ... you did have the right idea :-)  I was able to do basically what you described, only using the popup attribute instead, and it worked perfectly.  I'll post my working code in the original question (for syntax coloring).  Thanks so much!